# Problems Using Cursor Read From android SQLite3 database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I can't for the life of me figure why this code is not working.  It is following exactly the same format as other parts of my application save that I am passing two attributes to the helper method which should not be a problem and I am only returning one row which could be the problem but if it is I don't understand!

I have an activity that works until I call this command.

```
Log.d("Testing","Testing: " + cardID + " " + cardTypeID);
//LogCat displays the right values 11 1

Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchCard(cardID,cardTypeID);  // <--COMMAND
```

The helper method looks like this

```
public Cursor fetchCard(String cardID,String cardTypeID) {  
    String sql = "SELECT teamName FROM tbl_team JOIN tbl_card ON tbl_team.teamID = tbl_card.teamID WHERE cardID=" + cardID;
    //This returns 1 row when run in a SQLite Database Browser

    Log.d("Testing","Testing :" + cardID + " " + cardTypeID );
    // Program has crashed before this Log
    // Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    Cursor c;
    c =  mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);

    return c;
```

I'm leaning towards this being because there is only one row which has been read and I need to do a `c.moveFirst()` or something.  Would apriciate help in working this out.  Also why don't I get any write out to LogCat.  It seems to fail straight away???

PS. I have tried
        return `mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);`
Which I believe does the same as above.

Many Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mDbHelper` is null. Initialize it. And learn to use LogCat instead of guessing with the logs the row that crashes the app, it really helps.

Comment: You are right I had stupidly missed of the mdHelper initialization. Had a closing cursor error after that so added c.close(), then have a index out of bounds error now have tried c.movefirst() will get to the bottom of it hopefully.  So I do use the LogCat but sometimes don't understand what it is on about.  I only have 1 row, was using LogCat as a sort of breadcrumb like how far did get.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes at last it works.  Well I have only spent 4hrs on that tiny problem.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you have an empty logcat on app crash, check if your try/catch blocks and ensure you don't swallow any exception w/o printing them. Also debugger can help and show you the line that cause the exception and the variable that is null.